# Trying to change action bar size

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, styles

Ive been learning app development and have been working through XML. Now i am trying to find how to change the action bar size so far everything ive read has pointed me towards these lines of code.

```
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">15dp</item>
```

or

```
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
```

The problem with them is that i get this error

```
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'height'.
```

or for the first one i get the same thing but with actionBarSize. When i start typing android the suggestions come up and nothing related to what i want to do pops up. The only code i have is what is generated when you start up the app. I am trying to learn how to edit aspects of whats pregenerated please help.

Comment: Would you mind posting the complete "styles.xml"? Maybe that could help solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Toolbar`:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarSize"
```